# $I=\oint_C \frac{cot(\pi z)}{(z-i)^2} \,dz$. Confusion: Is $C: 4x^2+y^2=2$ a circle?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $I=\oint_C \frac{cot(\pi z)}{(z-i)^2} \,dz $ where $C$ is the
>   contour $ 4x^2+y^2=2$(counter clock-wise). Then find the value of I.

$z$ is a complex number.

Sources of confusion:

1)Is $4x^2+y^2=2$ a circle?

2)If $4x^2+y^2=2$ is a circle, then how can we change it into the form $(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2$.

3)If $4x^2+y^2=2$ is not a circle, then does $z=i$ lie within the contour of $4x^2+y^2=2$? How do we know that?

Comment: No, it is not the equation of a circle; rather, it is the equation of an ellipse. To answer your last question, at what coordinate(s) does the curve pass through the $y\ -$ axis?

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe  Got it thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$4x^2 + y^2=2$ is the boundary of an ellipse.  If you divide both sides by 2, you get the [standard form of an ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Equation)

$$\frac{x^2}{(\sqrt{1/2})^2} + \frac{y^2}{(\sqrt{2})^2}=1.$$

This tells you that the major axis of the ellipse stretches from $(0,-\sqrt{2})$ to $(0,\sqrt{2})$, and the minor axis goes from $(-\sqrt{1/2},0)$ to $(\sqrt{1/2},0).$

The points in the interior of the ellipse obey 
$$
(*) \quad 4x^2 + y^2\leq2.
$$
The complex number $i$ is represented by the point (0,1).  Substituting $x=0$ and $y=1$ into (*) gives $4\cdot 0^2 + 1^2=1\leq2$ which shows that $i$ is inside the contour.